# Dinamically lighten the background on each list item child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I have a stacked menu dropdown and I want each menu item to increasingly lighten gradually. I have done it manually using the sass lighten() rule, but I would like to know if there's a way to lighten it 5% dinamically for each new list-item increment. I guess some jquery should be combine to achieve this.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2fjzro4/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list-item-1">1</li>
  <li class="list-item-2">2</li>
  <li class="list-item-3">3</li>
  <li class="list-item-4">4</li>
  <li class="list-item-5">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can easlity do this via sass function

Comment: @HardenRahul, only if you know the exact number of items or have server-side Pug rendering. And then it would also have no sense to not just do it in the SASS.

Comment: Do you know the upper limit, or does it have to account for any number of list items? If you have an upper limit, go with a pure SASS mixin approach.

Comment: Thank you all, that's right, I guess you can't do it with an infinite number of items, there's just 5 right now and it'll be fine if we can simply count with a couple more added in the future, or up to 10. The sass @for function will do its magic!

Answer (score 6):

You could use the SASS's `@for`.

```
ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
}

@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  li.list-item-#{$i} {
     background-color: lighten(#333, $i*5%);
  }  
}
```

If you want it though to happen dynamically for the larger amount of items then JS is probably inevitable.

Comment: Wow, this is perfect! Just what I needed, since there wont be more than 10 list-items anyway! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Edit : @Michał Kostrzyński posted the same answer. Leaving this here for the CodePen.

You can achieve this with a simple sass `for` expression.
Don't use javascript if you have SCSS enabled.

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
    .list-item-#{$i} {
      background-color:lighten(#333, 5%*$i)
    }
}
```

See here :
https://codepen.io/Pauloscorps/pen/aVdrpY

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I agree it's wiser to avoid js if it can be achieved with scss.

Answer (score 0):

Use `each` and `rgba`

```js
var opacity = 1;

$("ul > li").each(function(index, element){
  $(element).css("background-color", "rgba(51, 51, 51, "+opacity+")");
  opacity -= 0.05;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list-item-1">1</li>
  <li class="list-item-2">2</li>
  <li class="list-item-3">3</li>
  <li class="list-item-4">4</li>
  <li class="list-item-5">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've tried this and it works great, this is a good alternative if you can't use scss or if you have a higher or unknown item count. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(var i = 1; i < 6;i++)
{
  var opacity = 1/6*i ;
 $('ul').append('<li class="list-item-'+i+'" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,'+opacity+')">'+i+'--'+opacity+'</li>');
  
}
```

```css
ul li {
  padding: 10px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Something like this maybe